# Ошибка подключения стилей

Tags: html, css, wordpress

При попытке подключить стили к сайту в консоль выскакивает ошибка вида: 
GET [http://сайт/wp-content/themes/mytheme../assets/css/slick-theme.css](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-content/themes/mytheme../assets/css/slick-theme.css) net::ERR_ABORTED
При этом всем сами стили не подключаются, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Покажите, как вы подключает стили, где реально находится файл стилей и какие у него разрешения и владелец

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проверить доступность директорий к правам чтению/записи
2. Как вы подключаете стили? Соответствует ли подключение спецификации WP?

   `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles');
     function enqueue_styles() {
     // Регистрируем
     wp_register_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
     wp_register_style('nm_lib',get_template_directory_uri().'/libs/lib.css');
     // Активируем
     wp_enqueue_style('nm_lib');
     wp_enqueue_style('style');
    }`